# LinkButton OnClick within a Nested Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble with a LinkButton firing the OnClick event where the LinkButton is in a nested repeater.

Here is my HTML Markup

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterGenres" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="LoadTitles">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnGenre" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GenreID") %>' />
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MovieGenre") %>

        <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterMovies" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MovieName") %>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbMovieInfo" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MovieID") %>' OnClick="LoadMovieTitle">
Access Info
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is my method to load the Genres. (have removed some of the declarations to simplify).

```
string sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Movies_Genres";
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, myConnection);
sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
if (sqlReader.HasRows)
{
    RepeaterGenres.DataSource = sqlReader;
    RepeaterGenres.DataBind();
}
```

Here is my method to load the Movie Titles within each Genre.

```
protected void LoadTitles(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // Genre from HiddenField
        HiddenField GenreID = (HiddenField)args.Item.FindControl("hdnGenre");

        // Repeater
        Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)args.Item.FindControl("RepeaterMovies");

        string sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Movies_Titles " +
                           "WHERE Genre = @Genre";
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, myConnection);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", GenreID.Value);
        sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (sqlReader.HasRows)
        {
            childRepeater.DataSource = sqlReader;
            childRepeater.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            childRepeater.DataSource = "";
            childRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything up to this point works fine. I get my Genre groups and within each Genre I get the movie titles that are flagged against that Genre, and also the Linkbutton against each movie title. It's the LinkButton that is NOT firing the OnClick event.

Here is the code i'm using for the OnClick event.

```
protected void LoadMovieTitle (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton linkb = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string args = linkb.CommandArgument;

    Response.Redirect("movieinfopage.aspx?id=" + args);
}
```

The solution I am hoping to get help with is what do I need to do in order for those LinkButtons to fire their OnClick event when clicked, and access LoadMovieTitle. When I put a break in this method, it does not break, telling me that the OnClick event is not finding or recognising it.

Comment: Does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61266397/5519709) solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [`OnItemCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand) to repeater and `CommandName` to LinkButton:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterMovies" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterMovies_OnItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MovieName") %>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbMovieInfo" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MovieID") %>' CommandName="MovieDetail">
            Access Info
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Server side:

```
protected void RepeaterMovies_OnItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("MovieDetail"))
    {
        LinkButton linkb = (LinkButton)(sender);
        string args = linkb.CommandArgument;

        Response.Redirect("movieinfopage.aspx?id=" + args);
    }
}
```

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/custom-button-actions-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/custom-buttons-in-the-datalist-and-repeater-cs